# Evaluate integral by interpreting it in terms of areas

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

[image]

I tried (a) and I got 5, but I am suppose to get a 4. I really need a good explanation to understand how to approach these problems. I tried searching in youtube and stuff, but it was not helpful. Thank you.

Comment: how did you proceed to get 5 in (a)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I would tackle it: For a), the function rises from $y=1$ to $y=3$ on the interval $x=0\ldots 2$, thus the average function value on that interval is $(3+1)/2 = 2$. The area is then width times height, i.e. $2 \cdot (3+1)/2 = 4$. For the others ...

$a = 2 \cdot (3+1)/2$

$b = a + 1\cdot 3 + 2\cdot 3/2$

$c = 2\cdot(-3)/2$

$d = b+c+2\cdot(-3-(-2))/2$